# How to implement roles and permission base on component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I want to know how to implement roles and permissions for users with multi roles.

Rules like this:

**Note** : R = Read, W = Write, D = Delete

| Role | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Super Admin | RWD | RWD | RWD |
| Marketing | - | R | RW |
| Customer Service | - | RW | R |

Please give me example with React Hook for implement this role and permission. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

really you dont need to do anything crazy for storing roles...

```js
const roles = [
  { role: 'superAdmin', display: 'Super Admin', feature1: 'RWD', feature2: 'RWD', feature3: 'RWD' },
  { role: 'marketing', display: 'Marketing', feature1: null, feature2: 'R', feature3: 'RW' },
  { role: 'customerService', display: 'Customer Service', feature1: null, feature2: 'RW', feature3: 'R' }
]
```